# flask: SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol error

Tags: python, flask, ssl

I have an SSL enabled flask webserver. Sometimes when I try to download a big file with my Ipad browser, I get an error. It works fine with curl and it works fine for smaller files on Ipad browser. This is the stack trace:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 362, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 326, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/home/adam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 301, in write
    self.wfile.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socketserver.py", line 826, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1266, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1235, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)
```